# Resizing zk-treecol at runtime

Tags: tree, zk, treecellrenderer

I have an application, where i should be able to re-size the width of a column of the tree at run time (as we can re-size the width of a column in spreadsheet.) because i don't want to wrap my data. Is it feasible.. ? if yes how can we achieve that ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this :

```
<treecols sizable="true">
```

[Here a fiddle with that option.](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/3tqq43h/20-Tree-sample)
[Here the official doc of sizable.](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Data/Tree#Sizable)